# Allow a way to search for text in spoilers

Tags: feature-request, search, spoilers

I previously asked a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245656/search-doesnt-find-text-in-spoiler-blocks) about being unable to search for text in spoilers.  Haney said that is by design to prevent users from seeing spoilers in search results.

He [suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245656/search-doesnt-find-text-in-spoiler-blocks#comment806390_246341) that I post a feature request to allow searching in spoiler text.  Two options were mentioned:

1. Make spoiler text searchable, but do not display the spoiler text in search results.
2. Add a `spoiler:yes` search option to allow searching in spoiler text and displaying it search results.